# Prevent <body> scrolling in iOS when touching iframe content

Tags: ajax, ios, iframe, scroll

I have a question that is similar to this question here:
[Prevent scrolling on HTML5 <video> element on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555612/prevent-scrolling-on-html5-video-element-on-ios)

Basically, I've used document.ontouchmove & e.preventDefault() to disable the scrolling on a page destined for the ipad/iphone.  No worries, that works great and there's a bunch of fixed elements that play nicely.  One of the things that is embedded in the site is the iframe-embed code from Vimeo.  My problem comes from the fact that, since the iframe content comes from a different domain and is in a different document, my document.ontouchmove & e.preventDefault() script is ignored within the iframe.  The default page scrolling behaviour returns when the iframe is touched, and the page starts acting weird as elements that aren't supposed to move, do.

I don't think there's *any* way to apply javascript from the parent page through to the contents of the iframe, but does anyone know of a way to prevent all native scrolling as a general effect?  (or maybe zero-out the scrolling as it happens?)

I might have to go to a more traditional, non-ajax-y view for this particular page in my site, but that ruins the overall look-and-feel.

The site hasn't gone live yet, so I can't post the address, but I can post code snippits on request.

TIA

Comment: Is this the same question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555612/prevent-scrolling-on-html5-video-element-on-ios